# Shared hosting: WordPress/laravel 5

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, hosting

I've develop a laravel web application, and I have to upload to a hosting that already have a WordPress application, the file system looks like this:

```
/..
  etc/
  public_html/
    ..
    wordpress_files_everywhere
    ..
  tmp/
  tmpsite/
```

I have not access to root folder, online to public_html, so I've created two folder inside public-html (laravel-backend, laravel-frontend).

So What I did is edit index.php in order to point laravel-backend files like this:

require **DIR**.'/../laravel-backend/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../laravel-backend/bootstrap/app.php';

Also I add this function to register method on app/Providers/AppServiceProvider

```
   $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
```

But the page still not found, I don't know what I'missing, My suspects is that I have to configure htaccess file in order to point my domain URL to public folder, But I don't know how to do it.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you trying to host wordpress with 2 instances of laravel?

Comment: No, i'm trying to upload a laravel application to a server thath already have a wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it by configuring the .htacess file as follows (Following the indications of this link http://enkognedo.com/internet/hosting-and-websites/89-multidomain.html)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wordpressUrl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} laravelAppUrl$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravel-frontend/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /laravel-frontend/$1 [L]
```

i really don't kwow if this has any security problem, by solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your url point directly to `laravel-frontend/public` and add extra `../` in index.php file. Assuming your `public` seats inside of `laravel-frontend`:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../laravel-backend/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel-backend/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Else, just rename your public folder to `laravel-frontend` and replace the existing `larqavel-frontend` so both folders are at the root level of `public_html`.

Also pay attention to how you type `DIR`. I think in laravel `index.php` it's typed as `__DIR__`

Comment: in folder laravel-frontend i have the content of public (no a public folder), so laravel-frontend is my public folder.
You were right with the DIR, i've change but i can't access the page.

Comment: Point your website URL directly to the `laravel-fronted`

Comment: But how do I do this? Should i configure htaccess or some other file? or is it an internal laravel configuration?

Comment: Configuring the `VirtualHost` aka `vhost`. Or something else according to your hosting company.

Comment: that was my first question because i don't know how to doit, in local environment I've configured a virtualhost in order to point public folder, but in this shared server i haven't access to the hosts files, i think a can doit with .htaccess but i'm not sure.

Comment: Nope. what do you use for local development? XAMP, WAMP? I recommend AMPPS as it lets you map virtual domain to a specific folder

Comment: that's correct, i'm using lampp for my local development, but i'm still don't know how to point my domain to a folder when i have no access to root, is that posible?